# need help understanding for...of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-of-loop

My teacher wanted me to practice for...of loops this is the example.
I've provided you with an array called numbers. print out the square of each value (the number multiplied by itself).
`const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`
Your output should look like this:
`1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81;`
I looked for...of on MDN i saw  you can add by doing
`(let num of sum); { num += 1; console.log(num); }`
so i tried `num *=2` but that will make 1 a 2 so I tried `num *= num;` . his answer came back as
`for (let num of numbers) { console.log(num * num);}` . I'm guessing mines is wrong because I  `*num;` and that's `NAN`,
can you explain why `num*num` is in the `console.log();`

edit: I think people are misunderstanding what i wrote  i wrote

`for(let num of numbers){ num *= num; console.log(num)`

Comment: `num *= num; console.log(num)` works aswell.

Comment: I think you accidentally put a semicolon right after your for...of statement. `(let num of sum); <- HERE { num += 1; console.log(num); }` That makes `num` `undefined` since it's not in the for...of block anymore

Comment: i updated my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Both of these writing methods are effective

```js
    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    for(let num of numbers){
      console.log(num*num)
    }
```

```js
    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    for(let num of numbers){
      console.log(num**2)
    }
```

Comment: I put the full work of what i had its deferent, also thanks  i didn't know i could use ** to times something by itself